# Sharing Yubikey via SSH

Tags: ssh, code-signing, yubikey

I have a MacBook which has a Yubikey. I usually don't use my MacBook for any development. I use a remote Linux server. I would like to sign my commits with Yubikey instead of a `gpg` key.

Can I share my Yubikey via `ssh` to my remote Linux machine?

What are the disadvantages? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is probably [Agent Forwarding](https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding), which let's a remote computer perform cryptographic operations using GPG on your local computer, via a SSH Channel.

That should allow you to use a GPG key stored on your computer or a key card.

A somewhat more detailed writeup [is also available](https://flameeyes.blog/2016/10/15/gnupg-agent-forwarding-with-openpgp-cards/).